# How to make Installments on product page get Final or SpecialPrice instead of GrantTotal?

Tags: magento, product

Maybe someone can help me on this one. I want to insert a dropdown installments on product page, and must show the price numbers with 2 decimals, for example: R$ 300,00 instead of R$ 300,0000. Thank you!
This is the code that i have and tried to modify it but with no success:

```
    <?php
    $standad = Mage::getSingleton('moip/standard');
    $api = Mage::getSingleton('moip/api');
    ?> 

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('o2ti_moip/css/formulario.css'); ?> "media="all">  

    <?php
    $_product = $this->getProduct( );
    $_coreHelper = $this->helper('core');
    ?> 
        <?php if ($standad->getConfigData('parcelamento')): ?>
        <label id="dadoscartaoopc">Parcelamento no Cartão de Crédito:</label>
        <select name="payment[credito_parcelamento]" id="credito_parcelamentoproduto" >
                            <?php
                                $parcelamento = $api->getParcelamento($_product->getFinalPrice());

                                foreach ($parcelamento as $k => $v): ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $k ?>"><?php echo $k . "x R$ " . $v['valor'] . " | Total: R$ " .$v['total']."" ?></option> 
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                                </select>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div id="addparcelas">
                                        <?php
                                        $standard = Mage::getSingleton('moip/standard');
                                        $parcelamento = $standard->getInfoParcelamento();
                                        if ($parcelamento['juros1'] == 0)
                                        {
                                        echo "<div id=\"addparcelasdesc\"> Sem juros até ".$parcelamento['ate1']." parcelas,</div>";
                                        if ($parcelamento['ate1'] < 13)
                                        {
                                        echo "após juros de 1,99% ao mês.";
                                        }
                                        }
                                        if ($parcelamento['juros1'] >= "1.99")
                                        {
                                        echo "Com juros de ".$parcelamento['juros1']." ao mês.";
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                     </div>
```

Printscreen of the actual dropdown: http://postimg.org/image/pokqf6xxj/03a4fda4/

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
     <?php
    $standad = Mage::getSingleton('moip/standard');
    $api = Mage::getSingleton('moip/api');
    ?> 

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('o2ti_moip/css/formulario.css'); ?> "media="all">  

    <?php
    $_product = $this->getProduct( );
    $_coreHelper = $this->helper('core');
    ?> 
        <?php if ($standad->getConfigData('parcelamento')): ?>
        <label id="parcelamentoproduto">PARCELAMENTO NO CARTÃO DE CRÉDITO:</label>
        <select name="payment[credito_parcelamento]" id="credito_parcelamentoproduto" >
                            <?php
                                $parcelamento = $api->getParcelamento($_product->getFinalPrice());

                                foreach ($parcelamento as $k => $v): ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $k ?>"><?php echo $k . "x R$ " . number_format($v['valor'],2,',',' ') . " ---------- Total: R$ " .number_format($v['total'],2,',',' ')."" ?></option> 
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                                </select>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div id="addparcelas">
                                        <?php
                                        $standard = Mage::getSingleton('moip/standard');
                                        $parcelamento = $standard->getInfoParcelamento();
                                        if ($parcelamento['juros1'] == 0)
                                        {
                                        echo "<div id=\"addparcelasdesc\"> Sem juros até ".$parcelamento['ate1']." parcelas,</div>";
                                        if ($parcelamento['ate1'] < 13)
                                        {
                                        echo "após juros de 1,99% ao mês.";
                                        }
                                        }
                                        if ($parcelamento['juros1'] >= "1.99")
                                        {
                                        echo "Com juros de ".$parcelamento['juros1']." ao mês.";
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                     </div>
```